# Создание миграций в EF Core

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

В общем, есть либа, где описаны модели, маппинг и контексты.

Выполняю команду:

> Add-Migration InitialCreate

И меня студия посылает нафиг, говоря, что файл должен быть исполняемым.

Ок, подключаю сборку в консольное приложение и выполняю снова эту команду, но меня снова посылают...

```
No DbContext was found in assembly 'ConsoleApp3'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.
```

Хотя в сборке есть 2 DbContext.

Подскажите, какой правильный алгоритм создания миграций в моем случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте явно указать исполняемый проект и проект в котором содержаться миграции:

```
Add-Migration InitialMigration -Project ClassLibrary1 -StartupProject ConsoleApp3
```

А вообще, должно работать и `Add-Migration InitialMigration` если у вас в настройках проекта стоит `ConsoleApp3` как проект для запуска, а в `Package Manager Console` вы выбрали `Default Project` вашу библиотеку.