# There is already an object named '[Название]' in the database при выполнении миграции

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

В общем, у меня 2 контекста, которые описаны в отдельной библиотеке.

Для каждого контекста я создал отдельную миграцию, как мне подсказали [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1093390/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-ef-core), задав еще для каждой из них отдельный output.

Теперь я хочу развернуть БД для отдельного контекста.

Я вбиваю команду вида:

> Update-Database -migration 20200312060742_InitialCreate -Project
>   BlaBlaBla.Dal -StartupProject ConsoleApp3 -Context
>   ContextName

И ловлю ошибку:

> There is already an object named 'TableName' in the database.

Из-за чего она может происходить? Мне почему-то кажется, что CLI пытается применить сразу 2 миграции из разных контекстов, так как эта таблица(на которую ругань) есть в обоих контекстах...

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, проблема была в конструкторе без параметров:

```
public PersonalDataContext()
{
      Database.EnsureCreated(); //<<---
}
```

Получается, что сначала выполнялось штатное создание БД, а потом накатывались сверху еще миграции, которые должны были создать БД.

Хотя, я вроде где-то читал, что миграции вырубают эту штуку...